# Can I use VLAN to interconnect two routers at home?

Tags: networking, router, vlan

So, at home, I have two networks; I made a little diagram of the essence of my network:

[image: My network]

Basically, I want the `server` to be able to be accessed by `private network #2` and I want the private networks to be able to talk to eachother (so that the devices from `network #1` can for example use the printer in `network #2`. I don't know if this works because both have their own DHCP (that they must keep). (Please note that not all end-user devices are shown)

Currently, the `server` has two ethernet cables: one to the `private network #1` (for in-home streaming etc) and one directly to the ISP (to get the public IP on that adapter in the server).

How should I configure this network so that the computer in `network #2` can access the `server`, and the devices in `network #1` can access the devices from `network #2`?

Can I do this with VLANs on a managed switch (Netgear ProSAFE GS110TP PoE Switch) while keeping the layout of both private networks?

P.S. I wasn't sure if this was the right SE, but there was a 50/50 chance! :)

Comment: What OS does the server run, and how many physical Ethernet ports does it have?

Comment: @grawity It runs Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard and it has 4 physical ports.

Comment: Also, how flexible are the routers? Can they do better than the basic "1x WAN, 4x LAN" configuration? (VLANs would help, but if you used them the way I'm guessing your plans are, then all traffic _between_ networks would go through the server...)

Comment: No they are very basic 1 WAN 4 LAN, and, I'd prefer if the server is just a client on both networks on a separate port (like it is now, there is a port for public and a port for private). Where public is directly connected to the ISP, and private connects to the router that also connects to that ISP. In that way, both networks can access the server for file sharing, and the cameras on `network 2` can connect to the server for surveillance. On top of that, I'd like to be able to access the printer on `network 2` from `network 1`.

Comment: Well, your options for interconnecting the two networks are _very_ limited then, since you can neither connect such routers directly nor through a third router (i.e. your server)...

Comment: If I leave out the interconnection between the networks itself, and instead make the server the only computer that can talk to both networks, it's as simple as plugging a cable in from both routers right? Because that's the main goal, the rest would be icing on the cake :)

Comment: In that case yes. (Windows 2012 _could_ route between networks in a pinch.)

Comment: I don't want to rely on the OS of my server (because it might change in the future). Very well, then that's how I will do it. I just thought having a good switch could lay "virtual cables" between these networks and allow me to plug in & out cables in both networks as I please. If you put your conclusion in an answer I will mark it. Otherwise I will put my own answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VLANs don't help much with interconnection – they only help you avoid having to drag a 2nd LAN cable where the first one already goes.

---

According to comments, your *secondary* goal is to connect both networks, but I'll start with it anyway – if you achieve it, then of course the server on LAN 1 will automatically be accessible from LAN 2.

The requirements for that are:

- The networks must not use the same (or overlapping) subnet.
- The routers must have the ability to add custom static routes. (It's surprising how many devices called "routers" don't allow that...)
- At least one router must support being on both networks at once. That is, either a) one router must allow creating additional LANs, or b) you must put a 3rd router in between.
- VLANs play no part in this.

Depending on your hardware's capabilities, you could connect the networks in two ways:

- **Direct:** Configure one of the two routers to have a 3rd network (in addition to "WAN" and "LAN"). It doesn't matter whether you create a VLAN on the router (let the managed switch deal with it) or dedicate a whole LAN port, as long as the router considers it to be a separate network with its own subnet.

  Specifically, it would be configured to have an address from the *other LAN's* subnet. For example, if LAN1 uses `192.168.1.0/24` and LAN2 uses `192.168.2.0/24`, then LAN1's router might have:

  ```
  WAN:  x.x.x.x/y       [DHCP client]
  LAN:  192.168.1.1/24  [DHCP server]
  3rd:  192.168.2.7/24  [no DHCP]
  ```

  This automatically gives it a route towards the other network, but the *other* router (LAN2) would need a static route to be added:

  ```
  Network (destination):  192.168.1.0/24
  Gateway (via/nexthop):  192.168.2.7
  ```
- **Indirect:** Find a third router – a more flexible one (e.g. OpenWRT or Mikrotik or FreeBSD or Linux). Win2012 could do in a pinch, but not recommended. Your existing server could *technically* do this, but it'd have to carry all inter-LAN traffic, which is probably not desired.

  <sup>(Although in the days of NetWare and VINES, *all* inter-LAN traffic was routed by the same servers...)</sup>

  Connect that router to both LANs (so that e.g. port 1 connects to LAN1 and has the apropriate IP address).

  Then, similarly to the direct example above, add static routes on *both* of the original routers towards the "other" network (from LAN1 to LAN2 via 3rd router, and the other way around).

---

Your primary goal was to have the server present in both LANs in any way possible, even if the networks themselves cannot be interconnected.

Since you have spare ports on the server, the simplest way to do that is to just physically connect it to the other LAN.

You *could* make use of VLANs on a managed switch in order to save a port, by presenting one or both LANs to the server as tagged VLANs, but that **depends on the server OS** being able to understand the tags, and to show separate (virtual) network interfaces for each VLAN.

Windows *does not* have that feature built in (although some server-grade NIC drivers do add support for creating virtual "VLAN" adapters). Hyper-V's "Virtual switch" would allow providing both vlans to *guest VMs*, but the host itself would still be limited to only one.

However, if the server's OS supported it, you could use this switch configuration:

- Port 1 (in: pvid 10, out: vlan 10 untagged) – to LAN 1
- Port 2 (in: pvid 20, out: vlan 20 untagged) – to LAN 2
- Port 3 (in: pvid 30, out: vlan 30 untagged) – to "external" switch
- Port 4 (in: pvid 1, out: vlan 10/20/30 tagged) – to server
- Or: Port 4 (in: pvid 30, out: vlan 10/20 tagged, 30 untagged) – to server

You decide what the best configuration for port 4 is; the basic concepts remain the same. Also, different switches have very different names to configuring this – e.g. "PVID" vs "default VLAN" vs "untagged VLAN". [Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHRtR.png)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. If I ever decide to interconnect them, this will be a very good tutorial :)